# Greek Characters in Google AutoSuggest API

Tags: php, xml, json

I am trying to use the google auto suggest API with PHP to capture search suggestions in Greek. I have tried 2 different ways and the Google API returns correct results but the native PHP `json_decode()` can't handle the greek characters and `simplexml_load_string()` throws an encoding error. When I use `utf8_encode()` first, the Greek characters become random letters or question marks in black diamonds when echoed out in a browser.

I want make a php file that converts this data to a json array that can be called via a `jquery.ajax()` function to give the user greek auto suggest.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Failed Method One**

[http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=el&ie=UTF-8&client=firefox&q=τραπέζι](http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=el&ie=UTF-8&client=firefox&q=%CF%84%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%80%CE%AD%CE%B6%CE%B9)

I get this URL with cURL then use `json_decode()`. The greek characters do not parse properly.

**Failed Method Two**

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=el&ie=UTF-8&q=%CF%84%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%80%CE%AD%CE%B6%CE%B9&output=toolbar

I get the data with cURL, load it into `simplexml_load_string()` then get a encoding error. When I put the data through `utf8_encode()` first, the encoding error goes away but the greek characters get all messed up.